# Is it possible to import Visual Studio editor/formatter settings to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I spend a good time customizing my Visual Studio text editor and formatter settings. I recently needed to use VSCode, it apparently has default VS settings. Is it possible to have my customized VS editor/formatting settings ( syntax highlighting, auto brace completion etc. ) in VSCode?